# Topology boundary and interior question

Tags: general-topology

I have this question that I need to answer:

> Find the boundary and interior for the following subset of $\Bbb R^2$:
>   $$A = \left\{(x, y) \in \Bbb R^2
> \,\big\vert\, y = 0\right\}$$

Surely the set of all interior points is just the x axis and the x axis is also the boundary, but that seems too obvious. Am I missing something?

Comment: What is the definition of "interior point"?

Answer (score 1):

The interior of the x-axis is the empty set and the boundary is the $x-axis$

Note that an interior point $P$  of a set $S$ is a point which has an open ball centered at the point $P$  and contained in the set $S$

Answer (score 1):

This set is closed and has empty interior (the interior is the union of open balls in $\mathbb R^2$, and this set clearly contains no such nonempty balls), so every point is a boundary point.